# Create a new connection of websocket from an opened one

Tags: websocket

I have a websocket that is created using this statement :

```
ws = new WebSocket(targetURL);
```

and my javascript runs all the function inside ws.onopen (which is only an alert, stating that the ws is opened).

However, after 15 minutes or so, I want to create a new connection of websocket using the same variable ws. I tried this again :

```
ws = new WebSocket(targetURL);
```

But this time, it does not look like that the ws.onopen function is not run (there is no alert stating that the ws is opened). So I assume that that statement cannot be used to create a new connection, can it?

Is there a way of doing it?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are creating a new object you must at attach an event handler. Handlers are associated with objects, not variables. Write your logic in a separated function, and assign that function to "ws.onopen" after creation.

Comment: do you mean like this :

function closeWS() {
 ws.close();
}

function openWS() {
 ws = new Websocket(targetURL);
 ws.onopen = openEvent();
 ws.onmessage = messageEvent(message);
 ws.onclose = closeEvent();
 ws.onerror = errorEvent();
}

Comment: "ws.onopen = openEvent", without parentheses. If you use parentheses you are assinging the return of the function, not the function in itself.